# Create Polygon with Mouse Listener Java

Tags: java, swing

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Triangle extends JFrame 
{ 
   public Triangle()
    {
    add(new PolygonsPanel());
    }

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Triangle t = new Triangle();
        t.setSize(500,500);
        t.setTitle("Triangle");
        t.setVisible(true);
        t.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        t.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
}

class PolygonsPanel extends JPanel implements MouseListener
    {
    private int x1,x2,x3,y1,y2,y3;
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
        {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Polygon p = new Polygon();

        p.addPoint(x1,y1);
        p.addPoint(x2,y2);
        p.addPoint(x3,y3);
        this.addMouseListener(this);

        g.drawPolygon(p);
        }

        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e)
        {

        }
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)
        {

        }
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
        {
            int i = 0;
            if(i==0)
             {
             int x1= e.getX();
             int y1= e.getY();
             i++;
             }
             else if(i==1)
             {
             int x2= e.getX();
             int y2= e.getY();
             i++;
             }
             else if(i==2)
             {
             int x3= e.getX();
             int y3= e.getY();
             i++;
             }

        }
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
        {

        }
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
        {

        }


    }
```

I want to make triangle using polygon and set the coordinate by click the mouse.
compiler did't show error, can anybody help ?
..........................................................................................................................................................................................................

Answer (score 2):

In order to debug such applications, you can add `println()` lines in the right places. While this sounds a bit childish, this method of debugging, called *`printf`-Debugging* is even used by the most professional developers in some cases.

I suggest you add a `System.err.println("1")` resp. `System.err.println("2")` / `System.err.println("3")` in each of the `if`-branches of `mouseClicked()` to find out why it's not properly recording the points. Hint: You probably want variable `i` to have a different scope than now`.

Registering the `MouseListener` should not be done in `paintComponent()`. If you think a little bit about this, it should be obvious. Ask yourself: How often do I need to register the `MouseListener`? Only once. How often is `paintComponent()` called? Many times. So, the `addMouseListener()` is certainly in the wrong place.

Once you fixed these, you might notice that you have to hide/unhide, resize or (on some OS) move the window in order for your polygons to be redrawn. That's because once you've changed the appearance by recording a new coordinate for your polygon, you don't tell Java that the component needs to be redrawn.

The programming model *usage by extension* which you apply is still shown on many web pages and in many books as of today, but it's plainly wrong because it often violates the *LSP - Liskov Substitution Principle*. In your case, extending the JPanel for a PolygonsPanel is almost right, because that is a kind of Painting Canvas which in fact is a new component, so, creating a new class that is a component is perfect for that. Just `JPanel` might not be the best superclass for it, check out the class hierarchy of Swing class a bit and you will discover a better superclass. However, in Triangle, you do not really want to extend `JFrame`, you merely use `JFrame` without adding any new reusable features to it, so subclassing is not right in that case.

Comment: plus one for 1Mio MouseLinsteners